# ZipArchive ignores password when extract

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

I create zip files with zipArchives with this code below:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docspath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *zipFile = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.zip"];

    ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [za CreateZipFile2:zipFile Password:@"1234"];

    NSString *imagePath = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"photo.png"];
    NSString *textPath = [docspath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"text.txt"];

    [za addFileToZip:imagePath newname:@"photozip.png"];
    [za addFileToZip:textPath newname:@"textzip.txt"];

    BOOL success = [za CloseZipFile2];
```

This code supposed to be Ok, when I go to my directory, exists the file and when I try to open, he request a password.

**Note: If I put the correct password the zip file show that password is incorrect...**

I use this code to open and extract the files inside the zip file:

```
    NSString *subdirectory = @"archive";   // the folder name to which you will unzip the files

        NSString

 *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *archivePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:subdirectory];

    ZipArchive *za1 = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    if ([za1 UnzipOpenFile:zipFile Password:@"1234"]) {
        BOOL ret = [za1 UnzipFileTo:archivePath overWrite:YES];
        NSAssert(ret, @"Unzip failed");
    }
```

With or without password he can *'Extract'* the files, with password extract the real files with real bytes, without password (considering that zip file is protect with password) he can extract the files with their names, but with 0 Bytes.

How to solve this?